# Event Handling with Timer to Poll Hardware

Tags: c#, delegates, timer, event-handling

I need to request values using functions in a DLL provided by the manufacturer of my particular piece of hardware (a weather station).  I'm new to C#, and the concepts of delegates/events are tough to wrap my head around.  Nonetheless, I've managed to pull the functions from the DLL and verify that data makes it through.  My issue is with polling the instrument periodically with a Timer.  In `Initialize()`, an object is instantiated, but the event isn't handled leaving the object null.  I'm out of ideas, and would like some advice!

```
public class HardwareData : EventArgs
{
    public float OutsideTemp { get; set; }
    public int OutsideHum { get; set; }
    public float WindSpeed { get; set; }
    public int WindDirection { get; set; }
}

public class Hardware : IDisposable
{
    private static Hardware v;
    private System.Timers.Timer hardwareTimer;
    private int counter = 0;
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();
    public static Hardware Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (v == null)
                    v = new Hardware();
                return v;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        try
        {
            hardwareTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(500);
            hardwareTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(hardwareTimer_Elapsed);
            HardwareVue.OpenCommPort_V(3, 19200); //COM port and baud rate are verified.
            hardwareTimer.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to initialize.", ex);
        }
    }

    public HardwareData LastHardware { get; set; }

    void hardwareTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            counter += 1;
            Console.WriteLine(counter);
            HardwareVue.LoadCurrentHardwareData_V();
            HardwareData v = new HardwareData()
            {
                OutsideTemp = HardwareVue.GetOutsideTemp_V(),
                OutsideHum = HardwareVue.GetOutsideHumidity_V(),
                WindSpeed = HardwareVue.GetWindSpeed_V(),
                WindDirection = HardwareVue.GetWindDir_V()
            };
            LastHardware = v;
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        HardwareVue.CloseCommPort_V();
        hardwareTimer.Stop();
    }
}


[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Hardware test = new Hardware();
        try
        {
            if (test != null)
            {
                test.Initialize();
                test.Dispose();
                Assert.AreEqual(0, test.LastHardware.OutsideHum);
            }
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Object is null.");
        }
        // Console.WriteLine(test.LastHardware.OutsideHum);

    }
}
```

Comment: You initialize your test and then immediately dispose it (killing timer).

Comment: True.  The way I saw it, the timer would go through one interval, load the data, and then be disposed.

Comment: No, you need to pause you thread to wait for the timer to fire. Try to add something like Thread.Sleep(2000) between Initialize and Dispose.
I mean do this for test only, in real application just go about your business and do something else.

Comment: Alternatively, you can bring your timer outside the hardware class into the test class and call the dispose method at the end of the timerElapsed handler after a test.PollHardware() call, or whatever you want to call it. You'd just have to make 'test' a global reference for the timer to access it.

Comment: Aha!  Thank you very much for that.  I can now test and see data being transmitted and the timer incrementing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with timers, you need to enable the timer and make sure the events are rasied:

```
hardwareTimer.Enabled = true;
hardwareTimer.CanRaiseEvents = true;
```

For Reference: [Timers on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcs6ww8.aspx)

**Edit**
In addition to the other comments to both the OP's question and this answer, the issue with the LastHardware being null is due to the property never being instantiated before the timer initially fires. To resolve this, you should instantiate the LastHardware property in the default constructor (or in the `Initialize` method):

```
public Hardware()
{
  LastHardware = new HardwareData();
}
```

Of course, you'd want to set some default values upon instantiation.

Comment: CanRaiseEvents is true by default

Comment: And timer.Start() is the same as timer.Enabled = true. I'd say the real problem is, as Alex pointed out, the fact that he disposes instantly after initializing, so there isn't enough time to do anything.

Comment: Herein lies my absolute confusion: in the test class, if I were to declare a counter for incrementing per interval, I wouldn't know what to wrap in a loop so I could test for multiple timer intervals.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)  {  
Timer mytimer = new Timer(100*i);  
mytimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(mytimer_Elapsed);  
}  
  
void mytimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)  
        {  
int i = ((Timer)sender).Interval / 100;  
            Console.WriteLine("Timer number " + i.toString() + " elapsed");  
        }